# Trie unsuccessful deletion

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

I have a Trie program written in C++. There is an issue with deleting Trie. Even though the code is performing delete operation memory is not getting freed. Can someone point where I am doing wrong? Program doesn't deal with the individual string deletion from Trie. Below is the delete snippet of code.

```
void deleteTrie(trieNodeT **t) {
    if(*t) {
        trieNodeT *current = *t;
        for(int i=0; i<26; i++) {
            if(current->children[i]) {
                deleteTrie(&current->children[i]);
                free (current->children[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

void deleteEntireTrie(trieCDT *t) {
    if (t) {
       deleteTrie(&t->root);
    }
}
```

Below is the link of entire source code:
https://ideone.com/xL7bvu

Comment: What exactly is it that leads you to believe that memory is not being freed? Freed memory does not get physically removed from the machine, deleted from the address space, or even immediately overwritten.

Comment: @ricl, thats true "Freed memory does not get physically removed from machine". I tried using gdb and when 'i' value changed , I tried to access current->children[i] - 'i' - previous value. I got the key intact and I am seeing that consistently.

Comment: Yes, and what did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is C++:

```
(trieNodeT *) malloc(sizeof(trieNodeT));
```

should be:

```
new trieNodeT;
```

You can't use `delete` and `malloc` together, it's undefined behavior.

Alternatively, you could replace:

```
delete current->children[i];
```

with

```
free(current->children[i]);
```

You also probably need to write out null into what you're deleting:

```
if(current->children[i]) {
    deleteTrie(&current->children[i]);
    delete current->children[i];
    current->children[i] = nullptr; // or 0
}
```

Comment: If I delete the pointer, why I need to set it NULL once again. In that case why at all delete? Particularly in this case. I always find the pointer and its value intact.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the delete for the root node?

You do not need to null the pointer for deletion to take effect. The memory is 'marked' deleted with delete statement. If you do not null the pointer, then the pointer still points to the 'marked' deleted memory area. C++ purists would jump up and say that what I say following is wrong - immediately after a delete, if you access the memory through that old pointer, in many implementations, the data would still be there. Because the memory block was just marked as deleted; NOT physically overwritten. BUT you should never access that deleted memory. The program takes away that marked deleted memory and assigns it away when it next needs memory; and you do not have any control over it. And with multithreading, that memory might be gone even 'immediately'.